# PHP GD: Crop polygon: Works with some images, with some not

Tags: php, php-gd

I want to crop out a polygon (that I have there a transparent area) of an image I saved from Google Maps Static API.
Then I created a second image, saved it and tried also the same script on it but with the difference that the was no effect/change on the second tried image but it's the same image. Maybe a PHP bug?
I'm using PHP 5.3.3.

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('map.png');
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('map2.png');


$black = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$black2 = imagecolorallocatealpha($image2, 0, 0, 0, 127);


imagefilledpolygon($image, array(0,0, 20,20, 0,20), 3, $black);
imagefilledpolygon($image2, array(0,0, 20,20, 0,20), 3, $black2);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
#imagepng($image2);
?>
```

Image 1:
[image: 1]

Image 2:
[image: 2]

Comment: From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php) "*alpha*: A value between 0 and 127. 0 indicates completely opaque while 127 indicates completely transparent."  So you're drawing a wholly transparent polygon, and you're seeing right through it?  Sounds like it's working as intended.

Comment: It should replace this polygon with transparency. The first examples works also correct, here's the working result of the first image: http://i.imgur.com/91Ska.png

Comment: Drawing with a polygon which is transparent doesn't replace the area you're drawing over, but composites the underlying image with the color of the polygon, according to the alpha value.  If you're seeing a solid color appear with the code you've written above, I speculate you are writing an image which doesn't have blending turned on.  Try calling `imagealphablending($image, TRUE)` and `imagealphablending($image2, TRUE)` and I bet you'll find that you get the same results then.

Comment: imagealphablending seemed not to work, I still get the same result. Just try my example code from above with the uploaded images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: You have to set imagealphablending **and** imagesavealpha settings for the images to get this transparency working. The problem also that these images have different bits. The working images had 8bit while the not working had 24bit.

```
imagealphablending($image2, false);
imagesavealpha($image2, true);
```

This comment helped me much: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#47083